# What happens when you write a simple program with a while(1) loop in a system with just one CPU and one core?

Tags: operating-system

It doesn't make sense that the system just freezes, but what happens?

Comment: The same thing happens in this case as in any other case of multiple processes being eligible to run at the same time.  That's up to the OS (as indeed is whether it is even possible for multiple processes to be eligible to run at the same time).  Just freezing up is undesirable, but it makes perfect sense, and indeed is the behavior that, historically. some systems have exhibited under the circumstances.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All modern OS are multi-threaded, and the operating system will do a context switch and something else (one of the many operating system threads) will run for a while.  Then it will context switch back to your while(1) for a bit, and repeat this until you go into the task manager and kill the process.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Context_switch

Comment: multithreading is what I am talking about.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multithreading_(computer_architecture).  Multi-processing assumes there's more than 1 CPU, and the question assumes there's 1 CPU.

Comment: I agree, but it is different, processes which are being brought to CPU and not threads. While during the time-burst of a process different threads might be scheduled to run by user-level library, in context switch a new process is being brought... (in OS where kernel is not aware of threading)

Comment: This is exactly how wikipedia defines multithreading. "In computer architecture, multithreading is the ability of a central processing unit (CPU) ...  to execute `multiple processes` or threads concurrently"

Comment: Nevermind this is not really important... context switch between user program and other program is switching processes and not threads but I guess you are right, you meant both ways.

Answer (score 2):

The operating system system schedules the CPU timer. When the timer goes off, it triggers an interrupt. That causes the processor to enter kernel mode and invoke the timer interrupt handler. This is where the operating system does its routine processing. While processing the interrupt, the current process is "interrupted." An infinite loop does not block the CPU's timer interrupts.

On most operating system a process has a time slice within to execute. Once the time slice expires, the operating system schedules a new process. That processing scheduling takes place in the timer interrupt handler.

On some operating systems, a process may be interrupted before its time slice expires if a high priority process is available to run.

The infinite loop just wastes the time allocated to that process.

Comment: 'An infinite loop does not block the CPU's timer interrupts' or disk, network, memory-management unit, KB or mouse interrupts.   It's misleading to only mention timer interrupts.

Answer (score 0):

The while(1) loop does not prevent hardware interrupts from peripherals lie disk, NIC, mouse, KB, tmier etc.

That one thread of that program loops on the while until a higher priority thread becomes ready and it gets preempted.

How, why and when that happens is up to the OS design. Higher priority threads that become ready upon hardware/driver signalling, (ie. essentially a hardware interrupt), would preempt the looping thread when their I/O becomes available. Many OS apply a temporary priority boost to threads that become ready upon such signaling, so another thread of the same priority that was waiting on, say, network data, would preempt the 'looping' thread and become running a soon as the data arrives.

Other threads of the same priority that become ready due to the expiry of sleep intervals, or similar, will usually be given a share of the available CPU at timer interrupt intervals.